# Правильная архитектура ( классов ) кода в js

Tags: javascript

Слово "классов" взял в кавычки, так-как уже объяснили, что в js это слово неуместно,
но вообще не упоминать его в заголовке, было бы не правильно.
Вот что мне не понятно...

```
var Test = function() {

};
```

Если рассматривать код выше с точки зрения неуместных классов, то этот код, является конструктором и я живу некоторое время с таким определением... Но дальше я иду на githab
в поисках кода, и почти в каждой библиотеке вижу, как этот код используют так, словно это тело не конструктора, а самого класса. То есть -

```
var Test = function() {
    // здесь определяют свойства
    var a, b, c;
    // здесь идет много методв 
    function a() {

    };

    function b() {

    };
};
```

Но ведь с точки зрения классов, это грубо... Или в js это нормальная практика и стоит взять за правило, что в js нет классов и нет конструкторов и нет вообще ничего, кроме обычных объектов. Где правда?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код, коду рознь, если хотите посмотреть стройную архитектуру, гляньте на Ember (хотя там уже перешли ES6), так же можно посмотреть на Backbone/KnockoutJS и т.п.

Возможно там, где вы смотрели, разработчик хотел получить приватные свойства и методы, которых нет в JS, либо он не понимает прототипы. Нормальные ребята так не делаю, а ограничиваются "_"-префиксом перед названием метода/свойства, если хотя «сказать», что он приватный.

Answer (score 1):

Архитектура, организация кода и используемые инструменты - это несколько разные вещи. Про первую говорить нужно в привязке к какой-то бизнес задаче и остальному стеку.

Организацию кода можно рассмотреть с позиции общепринятых стандартов, стандартов, принятых в команде (включая style guides), и с позиции здравого смысла. В проектах на JS, как и на других языках, принято делить ф-циональность на модули/объекты, обеспечивая low coupling/high cohesion, SOLID-принципы и т.п. Тут общая канва не отличается от любого другого продакшен языка.

А вот инструменты могут отличаться от привычных для других языков. В JS нет родной системы организации модулей, классов, приватных членов, классового наследования и прочих вещей. Но ввиду реализации ф-ций высшего порядка, замыканий и прототипной системы наследования, можно организовать архитектуру проекта, используя самостоятельно изготовленные решения для реализации модулей (CommonJS, RequireJS, etc), классов (даже боюсь выделить какое-то из сотен решений) и прочих вещей. Существует много решений для построения скелета приложения, которые определяют набор используемых инструментов (наиболее из них выделяется, наверное, EmberJS, использование которого очень сильно влияет на общую организацию кода в проекте и архитектуру приложения).

Важно понимать, что JS сам по себе является очень гибким языком, поэтому можно придумать массу способов реализации одинаковых с точки зрения ф-циональности вещей. Например, ф-ция может выступить в качестве конструктора, стоит только ее вызвать с ключевым словом `new`. Называть получившуюся конструкцию классом или чем-то еще, - выбор разработчика.

То, что описано в вашем примере, может быть как модулем (который вызывается один раз за время работы приложения, проводит инициализацию 'классов', объявляет переменные, используемые в замыкании указанными ф-циями и классами, etc), так и неумело описанным 'классом'.

При работе с замыканиями и при описании классов важно помнить про накладные расходы на создание и поддержание объектов. Если метод или ф-цию можно переиспользовать, лучше так и делать, а не создавать новый инстанс ф-ции при создании нового инстанса класса.

Также, очень важно, на мой взгляд, хорошенько изучить возможности и ограничения языка и платформы, для которой вы пишете на JS, не нести в организацию кода и архитектуру подходы из других языков только потому, что вы к ним привыкли. Один из очень толковых javascript-программистов, Крокфорд, считает одним из самых опасных заблужений насчет JS  предположение, что на JS можно писать, не изучая его (язык простой, конструкции все знакомые). Он же написал книгу ([JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596517742)) и провел немало лекций на тему использования JS в продакшене, которые, на мой взгляд, до сих пор остаются актуальными. Очень советую ознакомиться!